How to properly smooth a QPainterPath?
I am working on a Path drawing tool and made a previous post about how I could achieve smoother drawing. I have done some tinkering with cubicTo() and quadTo() but these have really not been much help. I don’t know if my math is correct, or how I would even calculate a smoother drawn path. Someone on my last post recommended a series of math formulas (polynomials) to achieve a smooth path. Any code snippets are appreciated.
    def on_path_draw_start(self, event):
        # Check the button being pressed
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            # Create a new path
            self.path = QPainterPath()
            self.path.moveTo(self.mapToScene(event.pos()))
            self.last_point = self.mapToScene(event.pos())

            # Set drag mode
            self.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.NoDrag)

    def on_path_draw(self, event):
        # Check the buttons
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            # Calculate average point for smoother curve
            mid_point = (self.last_point + self.mapToScene(event.pos())) / 2.0
            
            # Use the mid_point as control point for quadTo
            self.path.quadTo(self.last_point, mid_point)
            self.last_point = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
            
            # Remove temporary path if it exists
            if self.temp_path_item:
                self.canvas.removeItem(self.temp_path_item)

            # Load temporary path as QGraphicsItem to view it while drawing
            self.temp_path_item = CustomPathItem(self.path)
            self.temp_path_item.setPen(self.pen)
            if self.button3.isChecked():
                self.temp_path_item.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(self.stroke_fill_color)))
            self.temp_path_item.setZValue(2)
            self.canvas.addItem(self.temp_path_item)

            # Create a custom tooltip for the current coords
            scene_pos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
            QToolTip.showText(event.pos(), f'dx: {round(scene_pos.x(), 1)}, dy: {round(scene_pos.y(), 1)}')

            self.canvas.update()

    def on_path_draw_end(self, event):
        # Check the buttons
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            # Calculate average point for smoother curve
            mid_point = (self.last_point + self.mapToScene(event.pos())) / 2.0
            
            # Use the mid_point as control point for quadTo
            self.path.quadTo(self.last_point, mid_point)
            self.last_point = self.mapToScene(event.pos())

            # Check if there is a temporary path (if so, remove it now)
            if self.temp_path_item:
                self.canvas.removeItem(self.temp_path_item)

            # If stroke fill button is checked, close the subpath
            if self.button3.isChecked():
                self.path.closeSubpath()

            self.canvas.update()

            # Load main path as QGraphicsItem
            path_item = CustomPathItem(self.path)
            path_item.setPen(self.pen)
            path_item.setZValue(0)

            # If stroke fill button is checked, set the brush
            if self.button3.isChecked():
                path_item.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(self.stroke_fill_color)))

            # Add item
            self.canvas.addItem(path_item)

            # Set Flags
            path_item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
            path_item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)

            # Set Tooltop
            path_item.setToolTip('MPRUN Path Element')

I understand this is a huge undertaking, but I need some guidance. I am not a math wizard by any means. Or maybe I don’t even need math, I really don’t know.

The only difference I can see from your previous post is the mid_point, which is insufficient (and I'd be inclined to mark this as a duplicate of that, since the difference is quite marginal and you could've updated that post instead of creating a very similar one). You don't have to research about quadTo() or cubicTo() (which are strictly related, by the way), but about how parametric curves work. And, yes, you do need math for this, you can work it out with the help of Qt, but only as long as you really understand the math behind this.

For starters, you can look for bezier related posts, including those using Qt. Here's a list some answered by me (but many other exist): 1, 2, 3. Still, the problem remains: as already written, the control points of a Bézier curve are almost never consistent with the mouse positions. You must understand that aspect, so I suggest you to begin your research with basic trigonometry (circles/ellipses can be drawn with Béziers, if trigonometry fundamentals are properly understood) and »

» possibly use the above links to understand the underlying mechanics, since that's what you'd have to work with. Then, after thorough research, if you're still failing, consider providing a proper question that actually uses that research, or possibly ask it on [math.se] (but ensure that your basic concepts and math understandings are solid). Sorry, but, as already written, what you ask is not easy, and it certainly is not a matter of a simple "midpoint". Curves are defined by complex functions, and mouse events are just discrete points that may define them in very different ways.

To clarify, consider the case of the user moving the mouse very fast with the result being 3 mouse events: here is how Qt gets that. How would you draw that "curve"? One possibility could be this; those small circles are the control points, completely outside the mouse positions. Yet, would this be wrong? And what about this? And, with a further mouse event, which would be right, this or this?

@musicamante Thank you for an amazing explanation. Rather than just drawing the path, should i click point by point to define the shape? I feel control points may be easier to calculate that way. For clarification, I do mention Adobe Illustrator a lot and that’s because I am creating a graphics design program. I am trying to create tools similar to Illustrator, this path tool being one of them. I would prefer to draw the path smoother, because in my current tool I get these jagged edges. If you look at the pencil tool in Illustrator, you’ll notice it draws these clean smooth lines.

@musicamante My final question remains:
Do i need to use quadTo or cubicTo or any of these methods to draw smooth strokes? I feel there is an alternative…

What you want to do was clear since your previous post. As said, it's not impossible, but you must be aware of the logic behind such tools (which, sometimes, also considers the time relation between the received events) and know the math required to find the functions required to finally draw curves consistent with what the user possibly wants. You must understand how control points work so that you can find where they are placed relative to the mouse points, so you need to at least use trigonometry, and, therefore, really know how to use it (including inverse functions): do you?

@musicamante welp i really still don’t understand this so I don’t know what to do now

I really don't know what else to say to you: your problem requires math skills. So, sorry for being blunt, but if you don't have that knowledge, you either learn it, or renounce. You can't solve math related problems if you don't know math.

For those who are curious, I solved my dilema (With Math)
I basically just implemented a smoothing algorithm with Numpy and SciPy. Here's the code:
    def smooth_path(self, path):
        vertices = [(point.x(), point.y()) for point in path.toSubpathPolygons()[0]]
        x, y = zip(*vertices)
        tck, u = splprep([x, y], s=0)
        smooth_x, smooth_y = splev(np.linspace(0, 1, len(vertices) * 2), tck)  # Reduce the granularity

        smoothed_vertices = np.column_stack((smooth_x, smooth_y))
        simplified_vertices = approximate_polygon(smoothed_vertices, tolerance=2.0)  # Adjust the tolerance as needed

        smooth_path = QPainterPath()
        smooth_path.moveTo(simplified_vertices[0][0], simplified_vertices[0][1])

        for i in range(1, len(simplified_vertices) - 2, 3):
            smooth_path.cubicTo(
                simplified_vertices[i][0], simplified_vertices[i][1],
                simplified_vertices[i + 1][0], simplified_vertices[i + 1][1],
                simplified_vertices[i + 2][0], simplified_vertices[i + 2][1]
            )

        return smooth_path

To make this work, you just use the function:
my_graphics_path_item.smooth_path(my_graphics_path_item.path())
And you add the item to the scene, and so on...
You can also change the tolerance of the smoothness (I found 2.0 works best)
I hope this helps anybody with this peculiar problem.
